# Android Beacon Library, manifest file not seen

Tags: android, manifest, beacon

I'm a new user of Android Beacon Library. I have installed Android studio and Gradle as per instructions. I have downloaded Android beacon library from Github and when I open project in Android studio, how do I change the code to configure my beacons. I dont see the manifest.xml file at all. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which code sample you are using (showing it would be helpful), but if you are using the reference app there is no reason to configure your beacon identifiers, as it already is set up to match any beacon using a wildcard matching region.

You do, however, need to set a BeaconParser with the proper layout for your beacon type.  You do this by adding a line like:

beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
               setBeaconLayout("**put layout here**"));

You find your layout string for your beacon type (e.g. iBeacon or Eddystone-URL) by looking here:

https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com

There is generally no need to change the AndroidManifest.xml, but you do need one for your app to run.  Don't worry if you cannot find it so long as your code compiles.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine now. One thing I observed however is, when the app gets deployed on my phone first time, it displays "App just launched. I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " and displays the number of beacons correctly. Also has 'Start Ranging' button.  Then when I open the app second time and later, this second line doesn't show up but it only gives me option to 'Start Ranging'

Comment: The line you mention is only displayed when the app first launches, not when it is brought back to the foreground from the background.  You can force it to display if desired by killing and restarting the app.